# Scala - Writing dataframe to a file as binary

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a hive table of type parquet, with column `Content` storing various documents as base64 encoded.

Now, I need to read that column and write into a file in HDFS, so that the base64 column will be converted back to a document for each row.

```
val profileDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("/hdfspath/profiles/");
profileDF.registerTempTable("profiles")
val contentsDF = sqlContext.sql(" select unbase64(contents) as contents from profiles where file_name'file1'")
```

Now that `contentDF` is storing the binary format of a document as a row, which I need to write to a file. Tried different options but couldn't get back the dataframe content to a file.

Appreciate any help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest save as parquet:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#parquet(java.lang.String)

Or convert to RDD and do save as object:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#saveAsObjectFile(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thank you Dragonborn , but I've already tried to save the dataframe as object file, but the content is not what I've expected......this whole exercise is about read a document from HDFS and convert into base64 and store in hive table. And then read that base64 value and convert back to a document by writing the content to HDFS.

Comment: why do you need the blobs in hive? and what about parquet? it is compatible with parquet afaik

Comment: Data stored in hive is of Parquet itself. The problem is reading that and converting the content as a document.

Lets say a PDF document is converted into base64 and stored in the hive table. Now, we need to read that base64 data, unbase it and convert it back to PDF